# C# - Matriz de caracteres a partir de string

Tags: c#, string, matriz, char

Tengo un ejercicio en el cual se me pide llenar una matriz de caracteres "desarmando" strings que voy ingresando por teclado. Puedo cargar la matriz solo cuando las palabras tienen la misma longitud que la matriz, si ingreso una menor me tira error. Debería completar con espacios en blanco en esos lugares. Dejo mi código a ver si se entiende un poco mejor lo que quiero hacer.

```
using System;

namespace Ejercicio_2_SEGPARCIAL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de filas y columnas: ");
            int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            char[,] matPalabras = new char[N,N];
            CargarMatriz(matPalabras);
            MostrarMatriz(matPalabras);
        }

        static void CargarMatriz(char[,] matriz)
        {            
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Ingrese la palabra que irá en la fila {i + 1}: ");
                string palabra = Console.ReadLine();

                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
                {                    
                    matriz[i, j] = palabra[j]; 
                }               
            }
        }

        static void MostrarMatriz(char[,] matriz)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + matriz[i, j]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Ejemplo:
Si se ingresan las palabras EOLIO, ANANA, DIA, ALAMO, HOLA; la matriz generada deberá ser:

'E' 'O' 'L' 'I' 'O'

'A' 'N' 'A' 'N' 'A'

'D' 'I' 'A' ' ' ' '

'A' 'L' 'A' 'M' 'O'

'H' 'O' 'L' 'A' ' '

Comment: Pon un ejemplo para que se te entienda mejor

Comment: Ahí edité con el ejemplo del ejercicio a ver si se entiende mejor. Gracias por responder!

Comment: @naccsgo Pero como defines el array que envias a CargarMatriz(char[,] matriz)?

Comment: @Jorgesys lo defino en el main como char[,] matriz = new char[N,N] donde N es ingresado por teclado (5 en el ejemplo). La longitud de las palabras ingresadas debe ser menor o igual a N.

Comment: @Jorgesys ahi subí el código completo, tal vez se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = matriz.GetLength(0);
string palabra = "";

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Ingrese la palabra que irá en la fila {i + 1}: ");
    palabra = Console.ReadLine();

    if(palabra.Length <= n)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < palabra.Length; j++)
        {                
            matriz[i, j] = palabra[j]; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La palabra tiene una longitud mayor a la longitud de la matriz");
    }          
}
```

Cómo tienes una **matriz cuadrada de orden N x N** donde el largo de la matriz coincide con su ancho pues guardamos en la **variable n** el orden de la matriz, posteriormente ejecutaríamos el primer **ciclo for** pidiendo que se introduzca una palabra, después se pregunta si la longitud de la palabra es menor o igual a la longitud de la matriz, en caso de ser cierto se ejecuta el segundo **ciclo for** donde se guardaría en la matriz la palabra introducida, de no cumplirse la condición pues se muestra un mensaje en la consola indicando que la palabra introducida no cabe en la matriz por tener una longitud mayor a la que admite la matriz.

El error te daba porque el segundo **ciclo for** lo hacías basado en la longitud de la matriz y tenías que hacerlo basado en la longitud de la palabra.